# Custom Post Type link with post page WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have create a custom post type and then displaying custom post data but when I click on read more button of that custom post it's giving me an error `page not found`when I click on read more button it's pointing url like this `domain.com/abc/my-custom-post` here `abc` is custom post slug. I am sharing you what I did till now.

Custom Post Type

```
<?php
    function create_posttype() {

    register_post_type( 'abc',
    array(
    'labels' => array(
    'name' => __( 'ABC' ),
    'singular_name' => __( 'ABC' ),
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', )
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'abc'),
    )
    );
    }
    add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
?>
```

Displaying custom post code

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'abc',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
    );
    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
    echo get_field('featured_image');
    the_title();
    echo get_the_excerpt();
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Let me know how to connect with post page when clicking read more button.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and it is perfect but Here you can follow the instructions as per given screenshot to fix your problem http://prntscr.com/mozub7 and this is [reference link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen) Hope your problem is fixed.

Comment: Do you save permalink again with "Save Changes" button? because Click the Save Changes button to ensure any changes you have made to your Settings are saved to your database. so please click on "Save Changes" button in Settings → Permalinks and then after refresh the page (ctrl + f5) on front end side and check it.

Comment: @Jason Thank you for this. please mark (tick) as green mark of my answer so it can help for someone which is finding answer like this.

Answer (score 0):

do you save permalink?
in wp dash go >> settings>permalinks and save changes one time

Comment: Other posts are working fine I just want to connect custom post in single-abc.php after clicking on read more button

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working correctly. Try again to save the permalinks settings

Comment: How to do this? actually rest posts are working perfectly